# OpenCV 3 : Program not running in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv, windows-10

I am trying to run a simple image show program in Eclipse CDT in MinGW built using cmake.

OpenCV Include Path : "E:\cv\opencv\eclipse\install\include"

OpenCV Library Path : "E:\cv\opencv\eclipse\lib" (has all libraries eg.libopencv_highgui310)

My Code is,

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
    Mat img(500, 500, CV_8UC3, Scalar(100, 0, 0));
    cout << "LOL!!!" << endl;
    if (img.empty()) {
        cout << "Error: Image cannot be loaded." << endl;
        system("pause");
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow("Image Window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Image Window", img);

    if (waitKey(10) == 27) {
        return -1;
    }

    destroyWindow("Image Window");

    return 1;
}
```

When I build the code my console shows,

```
07:19:50 **** Incremental Build of configuration Release for project opencv_cpp ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ "-IE:\\cv\\opencv\\eclipseBuild\\install\\include" -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\faceDetect.o" "..\\src\\faceDetect.cpp" 
g++ "-LE:\\cv\\opencv\\eclipseBuild\\lib" -o opencv_cpp.exe "src\\faceDetect.o" -llibopencv_highgui310 -llibopencv_core310 -llibopencv_imgproc310 -llibopencv_imgcodecs310 -llibopencv_objdetect310 

07:19:56 Build Finished (took 5s.647ms)
```

When I run the program it just terminates and nothing happens. Even the print statement is not executed.

Here is the youtube link for the video of the problem,

https://youtu.be/kCrz_WPi_AI

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Even I too faced this problem for longtime. 
I researched through all the forum's , websites and all over google but i'm not able to find the answer.

**But suddenly I thought of *switching off the Windows Firewall and Windows Defender*, And it magically works for me.. You too try it and let me know the result !**

Happy coding :)